# Slow data-binding inside ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have an array of object in controller loaded when page is loaded, on a socket.io event i have to change the data inside it, socket.io is working fine and data is changing within seconds, But it takes 17 seconds to update in html

Here is my controller

```
  $scope.inprogresstasks=[{}];
    Home.getinprogressTasks().then(function (data) {
        if(data.data.success){
            $scope.inprogresstasks = data.data.inprogresstasks;
        }
        else{
           $scope.inprogresstasks=[{}];
        }
    });
```

......

```
socket.on('dripo', function(data) {
  if(data.status == 'start'){
    for(var key in $scope.inprogresstasks){
      if($scope.inprogresstasks[key]._id == data.taskid){
           $scope.inprogresstasks[key].percentage = data.percentage;
           console.log($scope.inprogresstasks);
            }
          }
  }
});
```

Here is my html code for test

```
<div data-ng-repeat="inprogresstask in inprogresstasks">
    {{inprogresstask.percentage}}
</div>
```

Comment: how many items are you displaying?

Comment: just 2 items ...

Comment: how many subitems?

Comment: need to tell angular to run digest since socket callback is outside angular context

Comment: worked with $apply  thanks you

Answer (score 0):

```
socket.on('dripo', function(data) {
 $scope.$apply(function () {
  if(data.status == 'start'){
    for(var key in $scope.inprogresstasks){
      if($scope.inprogresstasks[key]._id == data.taskid){
           $scope.inprogresstasks[key].percentage = data.percentage;
           console.log($scope.inprogresstasks);
            }
          }
  }
});
```

});